# REST API Format

Tags: rest

Say I have a React SPA that fetches data via REST APIs from a SQL DB. Backend language is arbitrary.

Does the URL of the API *have* to be of the format /api/v1/user/:id? Or could one just use uuid or a sequential numbering system like /api/v1/, assuming you have good documentation?

I ask because I have a use case where I don't really care about the route like a traditional web app, and dont really need the backend to format data. Just need a way to get the data from SQL to the UI.

Comment: If this API is only for your own consumption, it doesn't even need to be restful. You can have whatever routes work for you.

Comment: If in future you want to expose data from other collection then `/api/v1/user/:id` approach looks better, because here you are giving the collection name `user`. And if there is an another collection in future then you can create a new API. Whereas if you go by the uuid then you might have to change this API in future to incorporate the new collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the URL of the API have to be of the format /api/v1/user/:id?

REST does not care what spelling conventions you use for your identifiers.

```
/cb0becd7-24c4-4d79-97c0-0ad77a430cd7
```

That's *fine*.

From the perspective of a general purpose client, URI are effectively opaque (think surrogate key).  Any URI that is consistent with the production rules defined in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) can be used to refer to any resource on your server.

Because of that, we tend to look to other considerations to decide what spelling conventions to use - which spellings are going to be easy for our implementation to route correctly? which spellings are going to be easy to recognize when we are looking at an access log, and so on.